# Jquery select all checkboxes in table

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a script that should check all the checkboxes in a table.  It checks them all the first time, it unchecks them after that.  However, when I try to recheck them nothing happens.

the jquery:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(e){
    var table= $(e.target).closest('table');
    $('td input:checkbox',table).attr('checked',e.target.checked);
});
```

the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />
        </th>
        <th>
            hi!
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="1"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            hi!
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="2"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            hi!
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here's a fiddle of the behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/EEJrU/

Why is it not working after being clicked once?

Comment: It works with your code as it is if you use JQuery 1.7.2 instead of 1.10.1

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(e){
    var table= $(e.target).closest('table');
    $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bzpBB/)

[Attributes vs. Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Comment: Nice, terse, portable code. +1

Note that I was having trouble keeping the "select all" checkbox checked after the click event, so I had to add the following line to the function: e.stopPropagation();

Comment: In order to trigger a change event on all the other check boxes you should add .change() to the end of the line. As in: $('td input:checkbox',table).prop('checked',this.checked).change();

Answer (score 6):

Simple jQuery solution, with detection of checked inputs inside of the table, and state change for main (selectAll) checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $selectAll = $('#selectAll'); // main checkbox inside table thead
  var $table = $('.table'); // table selector 
  var $tdCheckbox = $table.find('tbody input:checkbox'); // checboxes inside table body
  var tdCheckboxChecked = 0; // checked checboxes

  // Select or deselect all checkboxes depending on main checkbox change
  $selectAll.on('click', function () {
    $tdCheckbox.prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  // Toggle main checkbox state to checked when all checkboxes inside tbody tag is checked
  $tdCheckbox.on('change', function(e){
    tdCheckboxChecked = $table.find('tbody input:checkbox:checked').length; // Get count of checkboxes that is checked
    // if all checkboxes are checked, then set property of main checkbox to "true", else set to "false"
    $selectAll.prop('checked', (tdCheckboxChecked === $tdCheckbox.length));
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #222;
}

table tr th {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #ececec;
}

td, th {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  will-change: color;
  transition: .2s color ease-in-out;
}

table thead .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover,
table thead .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover:after {
  color: #d80;
}

table tbody .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover,
table tbody .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover:after {
  color: #8d0;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  margin-top: -2px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg) scale(.75);
  will-change: opacity, transform, color;
  transition: .17s opacity ease-in-out, .2s transform ease-in-out, .2s color ease-in-out;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
          <label for="selectAll"></label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Join date <i class="arrow bottom"></i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr class="active">
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="tr-checkbox1">
          <label for="tr-checkbox1"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>example@gmail.com</td>
      <td>21 Oct, 2016 at 11:29 pm</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="tr-checkbox2">
          <label for="tr-checkbox2"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>some_one@aol.com</td>
      <td>03 Mar, 2018 at 08:36 am</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="tr-checkbox3">
          <label for="tr-checkbox3"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>another@mail.net</td>
      <td>11 Jan, 2020 at 01:47 am</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or vanilla solution:

```js
let table = document.querySelector('.table'); // table selector 
let selectAll = table.querySelector('#selectAll'); // main checkbox inside table thead
let tdCheckbox = table.querySelectorAll('tbody input[type="checkbox"]'); // checboxes inside table body
let tdCheckboxChecked = 0; // checked checboxes

// Select or deselect all checkboxes depending on main checkbox change
selectAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Array.from(tdCheckbox).forEach(el => {
    el.checked = selectAll.checked;
  })
});

// Toggle main checkbox state to checked when all checkboxes inside tbody tag is checked
Array.from(tdCheckbox).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    tdCheckboxChecked = Array.from(tdCheckbox).filter(el => el.checked).length; // Get count of checkboxes that is checked
    // if all checkboxes are checked, then set property of main checkbox to "true", else set to "false"
    selectAll.checked = tdCheckboxChecked === tdCheckbox.length;
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #222;
}

table tr th {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #ececec;
}

td, th {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  will-change: color;
  transition: .2s color ease-in-out;
}

table thead .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover,
table thead .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover:after {
  color: #d80;
}

table tbody .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover,
table tbody .checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:hover:after {
  color: #8d0;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"] + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  margin-top: -2px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg) scale(.75);
  will-change: opacity, transform, color;
  transition: .17s opacity ease-in-out, .2s transform ease-in-out, .2s color ease-in-out;
}

.checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
              <label for="selectAll"></label>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Join date <i class="arrow bottom"></i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <tr class="active">
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" id="tr-checkbox1">
              <label for="tr-checkbox1"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>example@gmail.com</td>
          <td>21 Oct, 2016 at 11:29 pm</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" id="tr-checkbox2">
              <label for="tr-checkbox2"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>some_one@aol.com</td>
          <td>03 Mar, 2018 at 08:36 am</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" id="tr-checkbox3">
              <label for="tr-checkbox3"></label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>another@mail.net</td>
          <td>11 Jan, 2020 at 01:47 am</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
        <th>Cell phone</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
        <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
        <td>2/5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
        <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
        <td>3.5/5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/></td>
        <td>Droid X</td>
        <td>4.5/5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
        <td>HTC Desire</td>
        <td>3/5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="5"/></td>
        <td>Apple iPhone 4</td>
        <td>5/5</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>




<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });

            $("#selectall").click(function () {
                var checkAll = $("#selectall").prop('checked');
                    if (checkAll) {
                        $(".case").prop("checked", true);
                    } else {
                        $(".case").prop("checked", false);
                    }
                });

            $(".case").click(function(){
                if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                    $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
                } else {
                    $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
                }

            });
        } );




    </script>
```

Comment: Looks like it will work, but it's excessive.  You don't need to put an if statement to determine whether or not you want all the boxes checked, you just need all the boxes to match the selectAll.  I do like that have the check to modify the checked status of the select all if someone selects all on their own though.

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful on the difference between prop() and attr(). Note this line in this article [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr):

"The attribute value reflects the default rather than the current visible state (except in some older versions of IE, thus making things still harder). The attribute tells you nothing about the whether the checkbox on the page is checked."

So in general, use prop() instead of attr().

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there is `<tbody>` within the `<table>`, finding `<td>` to closet table doesn't work.

It worked with me like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectAll').click(function(e){        
        $(this).closest('tbody').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```