# Tick all checkboxes in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, cakephp-2.0

i have table in that i put check box in every row. and delete records 
now i want to put check all and uncheck all option in header in my table

*below is my html output of my cakephp project.*

```
<form action="/" id="OrderOrderForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>view</th>
        <th>delete</th>
        <thead>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>
<a href="/orders/view/33" title="VIEW" class="fa fa-search"></a>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value="33" hiddenField="false">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>
<a href="/orders/view/34" title="VIEW" class="fa fa-search"></a>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="order_id[]" value="34" hiddenField="false">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" title="Submit" type="submit" value="Delete selected" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

**udpated. now i got 2 check box 1 for select all and 1 for deselect all but i want only 1. if its checkd then select all and if its uncheckd then delect all**

[image]

my check box html

```
  <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value ="Select all" class="btnSelectAll" title="selectall" >

<input type="checkbox" name="" value ="Select all" class="btnUnSelectAll" title="unselect" ></th>
```

**my javascript updated**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".btnSelectAll").click(function(){
    $("input[name='order_id[]']").prop('checked', true);
});

$(".btnUnSelectAll").click(function(){
    $("input[name='order_id[]']").prop('checked', false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164816/jquery-select-all-checkboxes-in-table

Comment: @KiranVarthi Its not duplicate .Here the question is modified to `ALL checkboxes have same class` And in Link u provided,there were multiple checkboxes without Any Common class .Getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working **[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UKJRM/427/)**

Use Button in HTML

```
<input  class="btnSelectAll" title="Submit" type="button" value="Tick selected"/>
```

In js use:

```
//After you click the button , execute the anonmous function block.
$(".btnSelectAll").click(function(){
    //Select All chackboxes having name as order_id[] And Tick it.
    $("input[name='order_id[]']").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Also you can give this class to `DELETE` Header (`<ht class="btnSelectAll">delete</th>`) also instead of button.

Comment: k thanks tick all working fine but what if i want to unchecked all.. means untick all.

Comment: k thanks its working but i am using check box rather then button. 

`<input type="checkbox" name="" value ="Select all" class="btnSelectAll"  >`

`<input type="checkbox" name="" value ="Select all" class="btnUnSelectAll" >`

so this 2 diff check box now i want only. 1.

Comment: Now ,Again ,Show your 2 Checkboxes u use in image Edit question.

Comment: hi. i want only 1 check box. if i check that check box then all value checked and if i uncheck that then all are unchecked

Comment: @newsurt , Use YOUR own logic,search on net.Its simple.How long wil u take help of people?>

Comment: k thanks i used if else and its working perfect :D. ya u r right

Comment: @newsurt U r a good developer.So search on net,learn/improve jQuery first.And believe urself.